# Does Hotspot Login window in Ubuntu allow saving file streamed by server?

Tags: login, network-manager, hot-spot

When Ubuntu 18.04 displays captive portal in the Hotspot Login window, is it capable of allowing user to save files streamed by the server? If the same portal is opened in Firefox browser for example, then the file download works as expected but in Hotspot Login window, there is no prompt to save the file.

```
$ uname -a
Linux ubuntu18 5.4.0-48-generic #52~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Sep 10 12:50:22 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

```
$ lsb_release -a:
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

Update:
On more testing it seems like the Hotspot Login is simply not showing the "Save file" dialog but automatically saving the file in Downloads folder. It is still a problem because user will not know if something happened when the download link was clicked

Comment: Please clarify your release. The closest is Ubuntu Core 18 as specialist *snap* based releases use the *yy* format, unlike *yy.mm* used by server & desktops releases (Ubuntu has had *yy* releases since 2016)

Comment: added version details

Comment: Firefox is a browser while Hotspot Login is just for logging in. Does the network host files at login page?

Comment: Thanks, yes there are some use cases that may need user to download/save file. I am just trying to get a confirmation if this is for sure a limitation in Hotspot Login window and if so, are there are recommended ways (user agent did not help) to detect we are inside Hotspot Login window and instruct users about the limitations of that and why users may need to either disable the connectivity check or just close it temporarily and access the required URL using regular browser.

Comment: added another update to the question